# number of trades in PineScript

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

Is it possible to know amount of open and close trades by bar (minute, hour or day) on market using indicator? Im trying to write cumulative delta with trades(not with volume)

Im not sure this information is presented, i red all docs but found nothing

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.